# How to migrate scr annotations of AdaptorFactory class to OSGI R6 annotations?

Tags: osgi, aem

We are migrating from AEM 6.0 to 6.3 and in process moving from Felix to OSGI scr annotations. 
I have a code like this

```
@Component
@Service(AdapterFactory.class)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "CustomManagerAdapter", value = "adapter/factory"),
        @Property(name = SlingConstants.PROPERTY_ADAPTABLE_CLASSES, value = {
            "org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver",
            "org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest",
            "org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource"
        }),
        @Property(name = SlingConstants.PROPERTY_ADAPTER_CLASSES, value = "com.myapp.util.user.CustomUser")
})
public class CustomUserAdapter implements AdapterFactor
```

How to multi valued properties like SlingConstants.PROPERTY_ADAPTABLE_CLASSES into R6 annotation?

I tried like:

```
@Component(service = AdapterFactory.class, property={
        SlingConstants.PROPERTY_ADAPTER_CLASSES + "=com.myapp.util.user.CustomUser",
        SlingConstants.PROPERTY_ADAPTABLE_CLASSES+"={\"org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver\"}",
        "CustomManagerAdapter=adapter/factory"
})
```

This didnt work. Please share an example of migrating multivalued prperties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To register multivalued properties, repeat the declaration for the property multiple times. The key, i.e property name remains same while the property value changes.

Ex:

```
@Component(
service = AdapterFactory.class,
immediate = true,
property = {
    "adaptables=org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource",
    "adaptables=org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest",
    "adapters=<Myclass>"
 }
)
```